# Is there a JavaScript library that speaks degrees instead of radians?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

There are a dozen questions here asking how to convert the result of, say, `Math.atan()` back to degrees so you can use it in a CSS transform or OpenGL.

The answer's easy (`180/Math.PI`)--but it's an extra bit of code you have to write every time you do trig.

Is there a JS library that speaks degrees? Perhaps with some other useful math functions?

Comment: Given that this library wouldn't interest a lot of people and that it could be written in a few lines, why not writing it ?

Comment: No because most calculations use radians for efficiency. It's only once you start needing them to be human-readable numbers that degrees come into play.

Comment: @dystroy, step 1 in an efficient solution to writing a library is to see if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Radians are used by most of the mathematical efficient functions working with rotations.
So every math libraries are using radians, because of all the good thing it implies.

A library using degrees would just be converting everything back to radians under the hood, making it pointless.

So yes, if you want to work in degrees you should have your input (I mean, the human input, whatever your application is) and the final output (here too, the human readable output) in degrees. Then, when they go to the "computer-controlled part" just convert them to radians with a class or function or whatever is suitable. The part being computed can and should stay in radians because no human needs to interact with them, and your computer doesn't care that degrees are cool. It is just more efficient with radians.

Comment: Depends on your design goal. If you want to improve execution speed, then yes, doing the conversions internally doesn't net you any speed. If your goal is ease of programming, and reducing the number of programming mistakes made, then a library is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The expression parser of the [math.js](http://mathjs.org) library supports units, including radians and degrees. So you can enter expressions like:

```
math.eval('sin(pi/4');     // 0.7071...
math.eval('sin(45 deg)');  // 0.7071...
```

Comment: Is there a way to get it to *output* in degrees as well?